# Module_eval in ruby. Metaprogramming, macros and modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

Help me please to understand how to work with method module_eval in ruby. I am interested in how can I include module m in class P in a proper way. It seems, that my include m is not working, but I can not understand why.

Please consider the following code:

```
module Mod
  def self.included(klass)
    klass.extend(Class_methods)
  end

  module Class_methods 
    def foo
      m = Module.new
      m.module_eval(%Q{
        def foobar
          "foobar"
        end
      })
      include m
    end
  end
end

P = Struct.new(:x, :y) do include Mod end

class << P 
  def method_name
    "q"
  end
end

p P.respond_to?(:foo)
p P.respond_to?(:foobar)

P.foo
p P.respond_to?(:foobar)
```

Output:

```
true
false
false
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: which class you wish to add the module to?

Comment: I wish to add module m in class P

Comment: why don't you use the `#class_eval` instead? or you need exactly `#module_eval`?

Comment: according your code, it seems that `Module` also don't respond to `:foobar` after evaliating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks for the tips, I have found two solutions in this situation. First with class_eval and second with module_eval but with 'extend m' instead of 'include m'

1) With class_eval

```
module Mod
  def self.included(klass)
    klass.extend(Class_methods)
  end

  module Class_methods 
    def foo
      self.class_eval(%Q{
        def self.foobar
          "foobar"
        end
      })
    end
  end
end

P = Struct.new(:x, :y) do include Mod end

class << P 
  def method_name
    "q"
  end
end

p P.respond_to?(:foo)
p P.respond_to?(:foobar)

P.foo
p P.respond_to?(:foobar)
```

Output:

```
true
false
true
```

2) With module_eval:

```
module Mod
  def self.included(klass)
    klass.extend(Class_methods)
  end

  module Class_methods 
    def foo
      m = Module.new
      m.module_eval(%Q{
        def foobar
          "foobar"
        end
      })
      extend m
    end
  end
end

P = Struct.new(:x, :y) do include Mod end

class << P 
  def method_name
    "q"
  end
end

p P.respond_to?(:foo)
p P.respond_to?(:foobar)

P.foo
p P.respond_to?(:foobar)
```